# Maven Surefire plugin is not copying JVM Options

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin, java-17

I need to upgrade my app to **JDK17**

However, after this upgrade, the tests fail with an error `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module`

I'm able to fix the error in my **Intellij** if I edit the test configuration and add the VM options `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED`

But when I specify the same in my pom.xml file using `<argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>`, mvn does **NOT** pick it up and I run into the error again!

**Any idea how to fix this problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.surefire.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <argLine>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.salesforce.atf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>salesforce-test-client-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.1</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.salesforce.atf</groupId>
            <artifactId>testclient-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stc-report-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see that you are configuring the includes which is not neccessary because those are the default. So in the end you can omit them.

Second to configure appropriate things for maven-surefire-plugin you should do it like this:

```
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <argLine>
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
      </argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Also I assume that you have to add those open to the maven-compiler-plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
          <arg>--add-opens</arg>
          <arg>java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
          <arg>--add-opens</arg>
          <arg>java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
          <arg>--add-opens</arg>
          <arg>java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
          <arg>--add-opens</arg>
          <arg>java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Also I would recheck if the error messages like those can't be solved in an other way. Maybe upgrading dependencies or alike? Have you used `module-info.class`? Module Path?

Comment: The above (first) worked for me. It seems that I was doing this in the incorrect pom.xml :-(